# What does "Everything's a copy of a copy of a copy" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Fight Club (1999)*, Narrator speaks about his health problem:

> Narrator: For six months, I couldn't sleep. I couldn't sleep...with
> insomnia,  nothing's real. Everything's far away. **Everything's a
> copy of a copy of a copy**.

What does "Everything's a copy of a copy of a copy" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People used to make copies of documents with something called a photocopier, instead of scanning and printing. They made poor quality copies. The narrator feels confused; tired. The world looks dull; faint; blurry.